# Custom stop method in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to make the error system for an R package more testable, and I have several error subclasses which I use to detail the specific problem encountered.

```
MyError <- function (call, message, someOtherData) {

    structure(
        class = c('condition', 'error', 'myerror'),
        list(
            message      = message,
           call          = call,
           someOtherData = someOtherData
        )
    )
}

err <- MyError(call('f'), 'this is an error message', 'this is some other data')
```

R doesn't properly format the call part of the error (at least for my needs), so I convert the call to text, paste it to the error message, and throw an error with the call argument disabled.

```
stop("f(): this is an error message", call. = FALSE)
```

This isn't a great solution, as I can't extract the call argument from the error message anymore. Ideally the error object that is thrown should include the messsage, call, and any other data I wish to use during testing.

**Question**:

Is there a (non-hacky) way to add a generic method to the `stop` function for specific error subclasses? I would like to write something like:

```
stop.myError <- function (..., call. = False, domain = NULL) {
    # -- print the error message using some custom error formatting
    # -- and then throw the error object as usual.
}
```

Apart from displaying the error object with different formatting it should behave identically to the default stop function.

Thanks for any help you can offer. If the question needs clarification, leave a comment below.

Comment: if you're doing a bunch of tests, the [`testthat`](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html) package is great. there are some others like [`unittest`](https://github.com/ravingmantis/unittest). and `?tryCatch` may also be useful to you

Comment: What do you want your output for the call to look like?  You say R's formatting of the call doesn't fit your needs but it is unclear what your needs are.

Comment: I have custom sugar that aliases x := x + 1 to function (x) x + 1, and I evaluate each inner call of ':=', as R prefixes it to `:=`(x, x + 1). Also I truncate some calls, and manually add readable stack traces to errors. Very different to the base `stop` function.

Comment: @rawr I've used both (I've actually rolled my own testing framework, this is a big project). I don't want to do regexp-based testing of error messages, it's very hard to maintain such tests.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'class' is in the wrong order -- `c("my", "error", "condition")`.

```
f <- function()
    stop(MyError(sys.calls(), "message", list()))
```

and then use tryCatch to catch your specific error.

```
tryCatch(f(), my=function(e) {
    msg = conditionMessage(e)
    cll = conditionCall(e)
    ## do what you want
}
```